# Reading json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET backend I am creating json file from a query, I want to use this json file and take some data from it.

I wrote this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $.getJSON("/Content/smartParkTotalJson.json", function (json) 
    {

    });
}
```

And now I want to see the json , take some data from it (there are many landmarks inside this json file and I want to take the ID element, latitude and longitude).

How can I get access to the things I'm interested in?

Comment: what is the problem accessing `json` object inside the callback and get what you want ? Start by `console.log(json)` inside your callback and then you will know how to access what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to parse your json data, use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). Pretty-printing is implemented through [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify); the third argument defines the pretty-print spacing.

```
$.getJSON("/Content/smartParkTotalJson.json", function(data)
{
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    var obj_str = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2);

    console.log(obj_str);

    // ...
});
```

For reading/traversing json objects in javascript, take a look at [this simple tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/javascript/how-to-access-json-object-in-javascript/). It can represent a good starting point for understanding the basic principles, and unless you provide an example of your json data, also your only choice to perform your data extraction.